# ECS auto scailing cluster with ec2 count

Tags: amazon-ecs, autoscaling

To deploy my docker-compose, I using AWS ECS.

Everything works fine, except auto scailing.

When create ECS cluster,

[image]

I can decide number of instances.

So I defined it to 1.

Next, when creating service on my cluster,

Also can decide number of tasks.

I know that tasks running on the instance, so I defined it to 1.

[image]

And to specify auto scailing policy like this.

[image]

As you know that, if cpu percentage up to 50 in 5 minutes, it automatically adds a task.

So finish configure it, I run benchmark to test.

In the service describe, desired tasks is increase to 2.

But instance didn't added automatically.

In the event log,

[image]

Maybe I defined number of instances to 1 in my cluster, So it can't start new task.

Why auto scailing do not automatically add new instance on my cluster?

Is there any problem on my configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ecs cluster Is not autoscaling the number of instances. It autoscales number of tasks that are running inside your existing cluster. An ec2 instance can have multiple tasks running.  To autoscale instance count, you will need to use cloudwatch alarms:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_alarm_autoscaling.html

You are receiving this issue because of the port conflict when ECS attempts to use the "closest matching container instance" which in this case is the one which ends in 9e5e.

When attempting to spin up a task on that instance it notices that this instance "is already using a port required by your task"

In order to resolve this issue, 
You need to use dynamic porting for your ECS cluster.

There is a tutorial on how to do this that Amazon provides here: 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/

Essentially, 
You will need to modify the port mapping in the task definition that has the docker container you are trying to run and scale.

The port mapping should be 0 for the host port and then the port number that your application uses for the container port.

the zero value will make each docker instance in the ECS cluster that is ran use a different number for its host port, eliminating the port conflict you are experiencing.

Comment: I used flask(port 5000) + nginx(port 80). If request to 80 port, it reverse proxy to 5000port. Do I need to change the port of the nginx docker image to 0? Or, just change port to 0 on my task definition only?

Comment: I only changed port to 0:80 in my task definition, can't access to it. Also health check failed.

Comment: If you are now having health check issues, three things to check.  1) ensure the health check is using traffic port 2) it could be timing out. Increase the time out 3) check your security policies. The EC2 instances might not be allowing traffic from the ALB

Comment: I added dynamic port mapping range to my security group, it access fine. But, still throw `already using port` error.

Comment: Are all containers using the dynamic port? It could be the flask application with the port conflict now. Is your flask app in a docker that you can dynamically port?

Comment: You know that I defined `Number of instances` to 1 on my cluster. I wonder that, regardless of cluster's instance count, auto scailing automatically increase instance count and register it to alb?

Comment: ECS scales the number of tasks, not instances. If you want to autoscale instance count use cloudwatch alarms. More on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205373/how-to-autoscale-servers-in-ecs

Comment: To running task, it needs available instance. But in my case, I defined cluster instance count 1. So additional task can’t running. You mean that I have to scailing instance with Cloudwatch. Right?

Comment: Cluster instance count can be 1 AND you can have multiple tasks running on that instance. Thus autoscale will add more running tasks (more docker processes running) to that same single instance. So additional tasks CAN run. Original post edited to reflect this.  Yes, cloudwatch will scale instance count.

Comment: Added more docker process to same instance? Is that general ecs running process on production? In general, auto scailing automatically add/remove instance. So until now, auto scailing on ecs works same with that.

Comment: Autoscale on ecs does not automatically add/remove instances.  It adds and removes tasks. Each task is really another docker process being spun up on your existing instances.

Comment: Overall your comments, there is two ways to autoscailing. First is launch more container to exist instance. Second is add more instance via cloudwatch. So, what is more prefered or general ways to autoscailing on ECS?

Comment: I think second is better way. Because, to implement with first way, instance always have to got free resource to launch more container. Is it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187435/discussion-between-sirlanceoflompoc-and-hide).